# QT Static library undefined reference to static variable

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

I have a problem with linking my project. I'm trying to create shared library which could be used between three different projects. This library will be used for parsing XML files and general handling with objects from these XML files.

Here is minimal example which is affected. Library project consist of these files

```
============= Library.cpp =============
#include "library.h"

Library::Library(QString name){
this->name = name;
}

============= Library.h =============
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

 #include <QString>

 class Library
 {

 public:
   Library(QString name);

private:
   static QString name;
};
#endif // LIBRARY_H

============= Library.pro =============
QT       -= gui
TARGET = Library
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
SOURCES += library.cpp
HEADERS += library.h
unix {
   target.path = /usr/lib
   INSTALLS += target
}
```

Main application is made by these files.

```
============= main.c =============
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "library.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   Library lib("MyLib");

   return a.exec();
}

============= Application.pro =============
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = Application
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
SRCDIR = $$IN_PWD/../Library
INCLUDEPATH += $$SRCDIR
SRCDIR = $$IN_PWD/../Library
INCLUDEPATH += $$SRCDIR

LIBDIR = $$IN_PWD/../build-Library-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Ladění/libLibrary.a
LIBS += $$LIBDIR
```

Here is the output of linker

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../Application -I. -I../Library -I../Library -I../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include -I../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../Application/main.cpp

g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/mint/Qt/5.5/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/mint/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib -o Application main.o   /home/mint/Development/test/Application/../build-Library-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Ladění/libLibrary.a -L/home/mint/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Core -lpthread 

/home/mint/Development/test/Application/../build-Library-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Ladění/libLibrary.a(library.o): In function `Library::Library(QString)':

Makefile:214: recipe for target 'Application' failed

/home/mint/Development/test/build-Library-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Ladění/../Library/library.cpp:6: undefined reference to `Library::name'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I change **static** QString name in Library.h to non static variable, then everything is ok. It could be linked then. I think, that project files are setup correctly, but what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, `static` member variables are essentially global exported "class variables" (so very different from other `static` variables, in a sense even opposite, you make file scope variables static to *avoid* them being exported globals).

And in that .h file, you only have variable *declaration*: you declare that this kind of variable exists, somewhere.

However, to actually make it exist for real, you have to *define* it. Therefore you need to add this to one `.cpp` file:

```
QString Library::name = QStringLiteral("initial value");
```

Additionally, it is class variable, so you (probably) shouldn't change it every time an instance is created, so your consturctor would be just:

```
Library::Library() {
}
```

If you want to initialize it from somewhere else (quite probably `main()`, to replace the code in your constructor, simply assign to it:

```
Library::name = whatever;
```

---

However, if you actually want to have it as instance variable (each instance/object of the class has its own copy), then just remove `static` from the *definition* in the .h file.

Also, with global variables (including `static` class variables), you have to be careful about initialization order. They're also global variables, with all the trouble that can bring. So, if you don't really *need* them, don't use them.

Comment: Thank you for your help, also for the theory around this topic ! Actually I want to create singleton, so the static will not be of QString type. QString was just for illustration. Anyway thank you for your support.

Comment: @user2336793 For singletons, you probably should read [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1008019/1717300) (or google for other resources). There are a few valid ways to go about having singletons, and many more ways which have different kinds of problems :).

Answer (score 0):

in C++, static member should be defined and initialized outside the class declaration.

```
============= Library.h =============
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include <QString>

class Library
{
public:
    Library(QString name);

private:
    static QString name;// declare
};
#endif // LIBRARY_H    

============= Library.cpp =============
#include "library.h"

//add this line if name is static member of Library
QString Library::name;// define and initialize

//you can also initialize it to other value like:
//QString Library::name = "banana!";

Library::Library(QString name){
    this->name = name;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Sorry. I just felt asleep yesterday. Answer has been edited. Thank you for your reminder.